# Histogram in Anomaly detection Deequ library

Tags: scala, data-quality, amazon-deequ

Can we use histogram analyzer in anomaly detection?

Let's say, I want to check for the change in the ratio of variables in a specified column. For example
histogram analysis for a column with Male and Female as values is something like (Male - 0.6) and (Female - 0.4).
Now If the value changes from these to some other values it should be an anomaly in the data.
I have tried it but couldn't figure it out.

Can we achieve something like this currently?

Comment: You are at wrong place to get your answer.

Comment: So where should I ask this?

Answer (score 1):

[AnomalyDetectionStrategy](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/anomalydetection/AnomalyDetectionStrategy.scala#L30) needs a series of Doubles.

As long as you can cast your computation as a 1D anomaly detection problem you can use deequ for this. For example, you could use a Compliance analyzer (instead of histogram) to compute the frequency of Males/Females and feed this into the anomaly detector.